# Mac UPS always shows 0%

Tags: mac, ups

I recently bought a UPS for my Mac mini home server. It is a Chinese brand. When I plug the UPS into my Mac mini, the computer successfully detects the UPS and the UPS setting pops up inside the Energy Saver preferences. However, the battery percentage is always at 0% and the UPS menu always shows *Unknown Time Remaining*.

[image: Menu]

[image: Setting]

I'm pretty sure this should be driverless right? The UPS didn't come with any driver, and the computer can detect the UPS. I tried installing [APCUPSd](http://www.apcupsd.org/), that didn't help, the app shows can't connect to UPS. Anything else I can try?

My Mac is a Mac mini (Late 2014) running macOS Sierra 10.12.4, the UPS is connected via USB.

Comment: Your UPS may not be providing that info to macOS.  It may only have the ability to tell macOS when the UPS is on/off battery and that's it.  Without knowing the brand or having some specs, it's pretty difficult to say for certain.

Comment: @Allan I did a little experiment on unplugging the power of the UPS to force it to go on battery, it didn't tell macOS that either, the Mac still shows that it is on Power Adapter. Right now it seems like the USB isn't doing anything other than making a UPS menu appear.

Comment: Then that UPS is not compatible with macOS at all.  Because when it gets unplugged, it should recognize it's on battery.